# Function recursing when it shouldn't

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have the following function:

```
followConnections :: [Connection]->Crib->Stecker->Offsets->Maybe Stecker
followConnections [] _ y _ = Just (y)
followConnections w x y z
    | fC /= Nothing = trace("Follow Connections recursing") followConnections (tail w) x (fromMaybe(fC)) z
    | fC == Nothing = trace("Follow connections fail! for " ++ show y) Nothing
    where
    fC = followConnection (head w) x y z
```

Technically, the function should recurse if the current element of `[Connection]` does not cause `followConnection` to return `Nothing`, or return `Nothing` otherwise.
However, by tracing the function I saw that it will recurse until `[Connection]` is empty even at some point it fails.

Any idea of why this may be??

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess- Does `followConnection` (without an "s") ever use `followConnections` (with an "s")?  Or does `followConnections` get called more than once, in a way where the output from the second call looks like a continuation of the first?

Comment: replace `followConnection` with Nothing. Does it recurse? Look for a call to `followConnections` from `followConnection`

Comment: If you want help, include just enough code for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Why does `fromMaybe` take one argument? Isn't that `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe`? Also, a case statement would make a lot more sense here.

Answer (score 2):

It makes a lot more sense to write your function using pattern matching and a case statement, which avoids all the calls to `fromMaybe`, `head` and `tail` that are currently cluttering up your code.

```
followConnections :: [Connection] -> Crib -> Stecker -> Offsets -> Maybe Stecker
followConnections []     _ y _ = Just y
followConnections (w:ws) x y z = case fC of
    Nothing -> trace ("Fail! for " ++ show y) $ Nothing
    Just y' -> trace ("Recursing")            $ followConnections ws x y' z
  where
    fC = followConnection w x y z
```

Since `x` and `z` are fixed in the recursion, it also makes sense to write this using a helper function

```
followConnections ws x y z = go ws y
  where
    go []     y = Just y
    go (w:ws) y = case fc of
        Nothing -> trace ("Fail for" ++ show y) $ Nothing
        Just y' -> trace ("Recursing")          $ go ws y'
      where
        fc = followConnection w x y z
```

Finally, you could use the function `maybe` from `Data.Maybe` to get rid of the `case` statement, simplifying the code even further.

```
followConnections ws x y z = go ws y
  where
    go []     y = Just y
    go (w:ws) y = maybe Nothing (go ws) (followConnection w x y z)
```

Now that the function is simplified, it should be a lot easier to work out where it is going wrong.